# Cache facebook/twitter profile image

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, twitter

I want to let the users upload their facebook/twitter profile picture as an avatar. I insert a record with their token/secret in the DB. I've made a script that gets the user's id and displays the profile image using `readfile()` but I want to cache this image for 30 minutes. Is this possible with codeigniter?

Comment: why cache the image ? save only the Facebook userID and use the url to get the image, this way if the users changes the profile picture you will allays show the updated 1
http://graph.facebook.com/userID/picture

Comment: I edited my question. I considered letting the users upload twitter profile picture and twitter API calls are rate limited - that's why I want to cache the image.

Comment: @N.L.telaviv - A fair point, but say you're creating a pinterest like comments system for a site where you could have a hundred profile images on a page at one time. Thats a hell of a lot of requests to the slow ass Facebook API.

Comment: in my opinion its all return of investment ... i would prefer not investing allot of time in coding this 30 minutes caching of user pictures and would just get API calls to get the picture , if you  think this will slow down the loading of a page with allot of pictures in it just load everything else before and the pictures in the end so the user wont be delayed from the data. take in mind to cache all users pictures you need to save all the users pics in your system every time you cache the pictures (so you still need allot of api calls and sometimes more than if not caching)

Answer (score 2):

Although not codeigniter specific.. On a site I created - when the user logs in with facebook, we download the file using something similar to file_get_contents.. we then store our local reference to it along with a MD5 of the image data.. This allows us to easily check whether we need to update our local store when the profile is next requested (this does require the server to re-download from facebook)

In other instances, we store the file size that facebook reports, so that we can do a HTTP HEAD request to check easily if its changed (I realise size doesn't have a direct relationship to the image changing.. however 99.9% of the time its a good indication.

Comment: As you have edited your question.. My answer still stands and also allows recognition for if the user tries to upload the same image multiple times from different sources (only the MD5 hash version)

Comment: OK but I still have to make an API call in order to check the size

Comment: Well yes - how else could you tell it had changed? Also any calls to any api for downloading images etc should be done outside of the client web request to avoid it slowing down your customers experience, etc..

Comment: I don't want to check if it's changed. I want to save the image to the cache for 30 minutes.

Comment: I was only trying to offer advice describing a caching mechanism - surely if you check if its changed - it means that you don't have to replace the image at your end + your end users will retain their local browser cached copy rather than having to re request it because the file modification date has changed on your server.. Plus - Facebook api for requesting the profile image URL is damn slow most of the time